# Cardinality of a set $\{A,B\}$ $A$ is a subset of $B$, which is a subset of $S$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let's say that $A$ is a subset of $B$ and be is a subset of a set $S$ of $n$ elements.

How big is the set $\{(A,B)\}$ then.

Comment: Do you want to know the cardinality of $\{(A,B)\}$, or of $\{A,B\}$? These are not the same thing.

Comment: the former option

Answer (score 6):

Assuming $A \neq B$, then there are exactly two elements in $\{A, B\}$, elements which happen to be sets $A, B$. Hence, the cardinality of $\{A,\,B\}$ is $2$. I.e., $|\{A, \,B\}| =2.$ Else, we can only say $|\{A, \,B\}| \leq 2$.

The set $\{(A, B)\}$ has one element, (cardinality 1), which happens to be *an ordered pair of sets*.

The information about the relation between sets $A, B,$ and between $B, S$ and the elements of $S$ is irrelevant: that information is what they call a "red herring."

Comment: Unless, of course, $A=B$.

Comment: Ahha, you're correct, @Chris

Answer (score 5):

The set $\{A,B\}$ has at most two elements, and if $A\neq B$ then it has exactly two.

The set $\{(A,B)\}$ has exactly one element, the ordered pair $(A,B)$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are asking to find $|N|$ where $N = \{(A, B) \mid A \subseteq B \subseteq S, |S| = n\}$ for some integer $n$.

To solve this, let's first fix some $B_0$ and let $m = |B_0|$. Then the number of subsets of $B$ is just $2^m$. Clearly, $0 \leq m \leq n$. So $|N| = \sum_{i=0}^{n}{2^i}=2^{n+1}-1$

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but to indicate that the OP's question could be *read* in a different way is slightly misleading. The notation is clear and unambiguous, and for the set(s) that the OP asked about, several people have answered the question. What you are doing is answering the question for the set (you think) the OP *meant* to ask about.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes, I see that my original wording is misleading. I will edit it for clarification.