# Cardinality of the set $\{(A, B) \mid A ⊆ B ⊆ S\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $S$ is a set with $n$ elements, what is the cardinality of the set

$\left\{(A, B) \mid A ⊆ B ⊆ S\right\}$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305876/cardinality-of-a-set-a-b-a-is-a-subset-of-b-which-is-a-subset-of-s

Answer (score 3):

CORRECTED HINT: Every such pair $\langle A,B\rangle$ divides $S$ into three pairwise disjoint sets: $A$, $B\setminus A$, and $S\setminus B$. Each of the $n$ elements of $S$ can go into any one of the three classes. That’s a $3$-way choice made $n$ times in a row. This can be done in how many ways?

Comment: still not sure how to go about with this. can you provide more explicit steps?

Comment: @user60862: I don’t blame you: my original hint was wrong, despite the two upvotes. The corrected one is right, and the solution is much simpler.

Comment: i'm not sure how the solution to a+b+c=n relates to the pairs (A,B), the answer to the equation is C(3+(n-3)+1, (n-3)) no? is that the answer to the problem?

Comment: @user60862: It doesn’t: see my revised comment and answer. I was inadvertently solving a slightly different (and slightly harder) problem. I apologize for the confusion; my mind seems to be wandering today.

Answer (score 2):

If you draw the venn diagram of the sets the solution will peek at you.

At first draw a circle or a rectangle or even a square signifying the set S.

Inside that figure draw a circle signifying the set B as B is a subset of S so it will be wholly inside the figure signifying S. Now Draw another circle signifying the set A and this will again be wholly inside B.

Now pick one element after the other from S.For each picked element you can put it in the one of the 3 regions inside the figure signifying S(If you put it inside S but outside B it means you dont select the element,if you place it inside B but outside A it means you select that element as an element of B only,and lastly if you place it inside A it means that you have selected the element as an element of A which also implies that it has been selected for B as well).

So you have 3 choces for each element. Now you have n elements so the total no. of choices will be: $3\dots3$ n times =$3^n$

Comment: nice approach‌.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $A$ first, then $B$.

For $A$ of cardinality $k$, you have $\binom{n}{k}$ choices.

Then $B$ is $A\cup C$ with $C$ a set of $l$ elements chosen among $n-k$, with $0\leq l\leq n-k$.

So the answer is:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\sum_{l=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{l}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}2^{n-k}=3^n
$$
which follows from a double application of the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0):

we have:
$$|\{(A,B)\in \mathcal P(S)^2 \mid A \subseteq B \}|=|\bigcup_{B\in \mathcal P( S)}\bigcup_{A\in \mathcal P(B)}\{(A,B)\}|=\sum_{B\in \mathcal P( S)}|\mathcal P(B)|=\sum_{B\in \mathcal P( S)}2^{|B|}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^k|\{B\in \mathcal P(S) \mid |B|=k \}|=\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^k\binom{n}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}2^k$$

which can be simplified by binomial theorem (as in julien's answer).