# Count of each (not necessarily distinct) element of the Powerset of Powerset elements

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let $X$ be a finite set. Recall that the power set of $X$ is the set of all subsets of $X$. We denote the power set of $X$ by $\mathcal{P}(X)$. It can be proved that, if $X$ has $n$ elements $(n \in \mathbb{N}_0)$, then $\lvert \mathcal{P}(X) \rvert = 2^n$.

**Question.** What is the value of
$ \sum_{A \in \mathcal{P}(X)} \lvert \mathcal{P}(A) \rvert$?

I imagine there is a basic combinatorial identity that I - an humble programmer - am unaware of.

Comment: This is a sum of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}2^k$, right?

Comment: Does your $N$ denote the finite set, or its "size"?

Comment: No, it is a sum of the form, $$\sum_{a \in P(N)} 2^a $$.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Anne Bauval, you are indeed correct.  I meant $2^ {|a|}$.  Also, to your first point, I meant $S$ is a set st $|S|$ = $N$.  Let me edit this.

Comment: @Ottpocket  I mean that you collect like terms, so that every $k$-element subset contributes a $2^k$, but there $\binom{n}{k}$ such subsets, so...

Comment: If $N=|S|$ denotes the size of the finite set $S$, then $$\sum_{a\in P(S)}2^{|a|}=\sum_{k=0}^N2^k|\{a\in P(S):|a|=k\}|=\sum_{k=0}^N2^k\binom Nk=3^N$$ (the last equality stems from the [binomial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement)).

Comment: @AnneBauval Would you consider turning that into an answer?

Comment: lol I was never going to get that.  Thanks Randall, Anne, and Air Mike for the help on this question.  The above is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310273/cardinality-of-the-set-a-b-mid-a-%e2%8a%86-b-%e2%8a%86-s?noredirect=1). @MikeEarnest I am first searching for a duplicate.

Comment: Well, I found no duplicate, so yes I am going to turn my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first find the distribution of sizes of the parts $A$ of $X$. This is conveniently expressed by the "size-generating polynomial" $P=\sum_{k=0}^nc_kY^k\in\Bbb{Z}[Y]$ where $c_k$ is the number of parts $A$ of $X$ of size $k$. You probably know that $c_k=\binom nk$ and therefore $P=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}kY^k=(1+Y)^n$ by the binomial theorem. Now for every part $A$ of size $k$ you want to contribute $2^k$; since such a part contributed $1$ to the coefficient $c_k$ of $Y^k$, your summation simply becomes the result of substituting $Y=2$ into $P$; this gives $P[Y:=2]=(1+2)^n=3^n$ as value.

Answer (score 1):

If $n=|X|$ denotes the size of the finite set $X$, then
$$\begin{align}\sum_{A \in \mathcal{P}(X)} \lvert \mathcal{P}(A) \rvert&=\sum_{A\in P(X)}2^{|A|}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^n2^k\;|\{A\in P(X):|A|=k\}|\\&=\sum_{k=0}^n2^k\binom nk\\&=3^n\end{align}$$
(the last equality stems from the [binomial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement)).

Alternatively, you can find a very nice "direct" proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88064/386889), if you first realize that
$$\sum_{B\in \mathcal P(X)}\lvert\mathcal P(B) \rvert=
\lvert\{(A,B):A\subseteq B\subseteq X\}\rvert.$$